# mongoengine & mLab with Elastic Beanstalk autoscaling

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mongoengine, mlab

I am using a MongoDB database hosted through mLab, connecting via mongoengine, on an Elastic Beanstalk (Flask) application.

I am connecting like so:

```
mongoengine.connect(db='my-database', host ='mongodb:/user:password@xxx.mlab.com')
```

However the first time Elastic Beanstalk autoscaled my application, I started to receive the following error message:

```
OperationFailure: Another user is already authenticated to this database. 
You must logout first.
```

I think this is happening because the same user is trying to authenticate to the same database multiple times as the application auto-scales? If that is the case, what is the solution? Is there a different way I should be connecting to the database?

Comment: I'm getting this error as well using `mongoengine==0.15.0`. Could you specify your versions?

Comment: @KBoehme `mongoengine==0.15.0` &  `MongoDB version 3.6.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this is the case, but I found that downgrading from `pymongo==3.7.0` to `pymongo==3.6.1` under the hood of `mongoengine` resolved the issue for me